# How to photograph flat plastic in an "interesting" way to show off its properties?

Tags: lighting, macro, technique, composition, product-photography

At work we are currently in the process of photographing samples of materials. The idea is to photograph them to show their structure/properties more than their shape (i.e. if we have a steel cog, we want to show a close-up of the surface and not just a picture of a cog). We are using a macro lens to enable us to get these close-up pictures.

Some of the materials that we are photographing however are just flat plastic sheets. We have several types of plastic, so want to do something so that they don't just all look the same.

What is the best way to photograph them? An additional challenge is that some of them are clear and transparent. How do we photograph these?

---

As an example, we have this sample:

[image]

which we have photographed like this:

[image]

and here is an example of a transparent sample:

[image]

---

**EDIT:** A lot of the discussion is focused on the transparent aspect of the samples. While this is good as we have several of these and the suggested techniques show how to show off the transparency, we also have some that are opaque which we need to photograph in the same way. For example:

[image]

Comment: What is the purpose of it all. Documentation or marketing?

Comment: @Hugo: Marketing really. We are a company that provide information on materials, and this is part of a small marketing site to show off some of that data. We want some nice photos of the materials to go along with the data.

Comment: I see. Are there some special surface properties like roughness or coating maybe? If so you could be creative with that

Comment: For these samples, unfortunately no. They are just smooth, flat, square plastic sheets. Hence the trouble we are having photographing them :)

Comment: Ok, then I would darken the set and use a flash set up to make interesting lighting effects within the plastic itself. Think the prisma in Pink Floyd's "Dark side of the moon", even though the refraction won't be as spectacular.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted. This is on topic and you've clearly tried some things already. Maybe it would help of you expanded on the rather subjective term "interesting"?

Comment: Is accurate reproduction of the color for colored samples important?

Comment: Is there any visible distinction in the properties of the plastic sheets other than color and transparency that needs to emphasized, such as thickness, surface treatment, etc?

Comment: @Icycle: Accurate colour reproduction: not really, as the colour of the samples is fairly arbitrary. Visible distinction in the properties: no, just colour and transparency.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean when you say the products must be photographed "in the same way"?  Are all the samples identical in size and shape and must appear the same size and shape in the images?  Must they have the same background color?  Must they use the same photographic setup for simplicity and repeatability?  Opaque and transparent subjects have very different characteristics that lead to different optimal lighting techniques, so to address your edit, it's very important to specify what the additional constraints are.

Comment: @Icycle: by "the same way" I mean to show off their structure/properties. We have many samples of all shapes and sizes. Most of them are easy to photograph as they are lattices or have interesting surfaces. The plastics are what we are struggling with as they tend to be very similar to each other and are just a boring flat square. They don't need the same background colour (at the moment we have used both black and white depending on the colour of the sample), lighting or set up - we just want to show each sample off as best we can.

Comment: I assume the existing answers adequately address the transparent samples.  For the opaque samples you say that the color is arbitrary and that there aren't any other important properties to display. Do you just mean that a blue sample just needs to appear somewhere in the neighborhood of blue rather that a specific shade? Or that its color really is arbitrary and all the matters is that it is colored as opposed to white or transparent?

Comment: And are you looking more for composition suggestions or lighting suggestions?

Comment: @Icycle: "I assume the existing answers adequately address the transparent samples" - yes, they have been very useful. "are you looking more for composition suggestions or lighting suggestions" - to be honest, I'm now not sure. I _think_ I'm trying to ask for advice on how to photograph a flat boring square of opaque plastic to make it more interesting to look at than just a face-on shot of it. As the colour of plastic can be anything (as it is just dyed), the colour is less important that how it appears (e.g. its surface).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To address your second question first:  Transparent subjects can be tough to photograph in a flattering manner, but there are a couple of good lighting set ups that give pleasing results.

In bright field lighting, you set up your subject in front of a bright white background that just fills the frame. The area outside the bright background should be dark. The background can either be lit from behind (e.g. a softbox diffuser) or from the front (e.g. white card with a flash aimed at it.). The bright background will shine though the subject, but its edges will be clearly outlined in black, caused by refraction of the dark areas surrounding the bright background. Here is an example:  [image: bright field lighting example]http://www.flickr.com/photos/10295241@N02/12165904053/

In dark field lighting, the setup is reversed. The subject is in front of a dark, unlit background that just fills the frame, and the surrounding area just outside the frame is brightly light (e.g. a dark card in front of a brightly lit background). The subject will be dark like the background, but its edges will be bright due to refracting the bright area just outside the frame. Here is an example: [image: edark field lighting example]http://www.flickr.com/photos/10295241@N02/10917903153/

For additional details on these and other lighting techniques, I strongly recommend the book "[Light Science and Magic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0240812255)", which takes a first principles approach to using light in photography.

To address your first question, how best to present your "flat, boring subjects" really depends on the constraints you are operating under.  You could look at product photography in catalogs and advertisements to gets some ideas of how to present your product.   One option might be to set the subject against a separately lit seamless white background.  Optionally, the subject could be placed on a reflective surface (as in the bowls picture above) to a reflection of the subject to make it more interesting than just floating alone in space.  Another option might be to place the subject in an interesting setting, perhaps in or suggestive of the context in which it would be used (workshop?  drafting table?).  Yet another option might be to have the subject held by a hand model.  What works best for you may depend on both your creativity as well as the limits imposed by the final context of the images.

Comment: I'd like to add to this that your bright field lighting example above shows the objects placed on a reflective surface, I think that in itself can be a useful method to enhance the image when photographing subjects like this :)

Answer (score 1):

Lighting is going to be very key.  It is also probably a good idea to have a background or some object behind them (but out of focus) that can demonstrate their level of transparency clearly.  You will have to play around with it, but you probably want one light to be positioned to be at-least close to incident with the plastic to show how much it reflects (the highlighting on the plastic will make it more visual interesting than just a flat matte plastic).

As far as a background object, you might want to set up multiple samples at different angles that overlap.  This would let it still be the product in the shot, but if you had three different pieces positioned in an interesting way and overlapping each other you would get a nice feel for the transparency.

Answer (score 1):

I would show the transparency with a split background. The plastic rectangle is laid down on the table, one half is over clean white background, one half is over a small-patterned background (e.g. color+white checkered). I would not use perspective, just plain top view, but that up to you. If translucency is important, I would cast light through the plastic on the white part of the split background, and I would raise the plastic a bit so you get a bit of diffuse light cast.

Now, if reflectivity is a key, I would show that with a different setup. I would put down the plastic rectangle on the table vertically, totally facing me, would cast a light on the left corner angling down on the rectangle, and casting reflected light on the bottom right, on the table (I am a bit above the table level, so I see the surface of the table). If the reflected light is colorized, I would use a neutral white lamp for this. A harmonizing background color (simple or gradient) could be a nice complenent to this setup.